# Shell script to run command on remote host from jumphost reading from csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need help to parse the csv file containing server names in columnA & respective json file to be opened from our Jumphost in columnB ( passwordless authentication is working from jumphost to all servers)

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2
do
for HOSTNAME in field1 ;do
 ssh -tt -q $field1 'cat $field2'
 done
done < INC-State.csv
```

The csv file loos like below

```
 ServerName,Filename
Server1,/apps/logstash1.json
Server2,/apps/logstash2.json
```

When I am executing the script, getting output as below

```
    ServerName,Filename
    Server1,logstash1.json
    Server2,logstash2.json
```

I am facing 2 issues

1. ssh issue to suppress the motd or banner which comes up during ssh login which was done using -q and terminal getting stuck which was answered using -tt flag ( not sure whether its correct)
2. Its printing only the file names not the content of the file ( like $field2)
   Can someone please help here

Answer (score 1):

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net

> 1. ssh issue to suppress the motd

Remove `-tt`.  Also `ssh` eats stdin - close stdin for `ssh`. `ssh stuff <&-`.

> 2. Its printing only

Variable expansions do not expand in single quotes. Use double quotes. Additionally, use meaningful variable names....

```
while IFS=, read -r server file; do
    ssh "$server" "cat $file" <&-
done < inputfile
```

Commands in `ssh` are re-`eval`-ed. For correctness, you should quote arguments.

```
    ssh "$server" "cat $(printf "%q" "$file")" <&-
```

---

Note that the first line of csv is the header. Omit it.

```
{ 
    read _             # empty read first line
    while IFS=, read ....
         ...
    done
} < inputfile.csv
```